# Manufacturing desired planks from an existing pile of planks

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, conjectures, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose there is a pile of commensurable planks that only may differ in lengths $0<a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_m$, which are to be used to manufacture planks of length: $0<b_1\leq\cdots\leq b_n$.

> **Algorithm**:
> $A$ is the list of existent planks
> $B$ is the list of wanted planks
>
> 1. If $B$ is empty return 'success'
> 2. If $a_m<b_1$ return 'failure'
> 3. Remove the smallest plank $a_i\geq b_1$ from list $A$
> 4. Manufacture the greatest plank $b_j\leq a_i$ by, if necessary, cut $a_i$ into planks of length $b_j$ and $a^\prime_i$
> 5. Return what's left ($a^\prime_i$) to $A$
> 6. Remove $b_j$ from the list $B$
> 7. Goto 1.

I conjecture that this algorithm is optimal in two ways:

> 1. If the manufacturing is possible in any way, it is also possible by the algorithm.
> 2. The square sum of the lengths of the remaining planks in $A$ is maximal compared to other cuttings.

Is this possible to prove or disprove?

Comment: Note for googling purposes: The problem your algorithm tries to solve is checking whether the integer partition $\left(b_n, \ldots, b_1\right)$ is a refinement of the partition $\left(a_m, \ldots, a_1\right)$ (and if so, finding a witness). I'd suspect Knuth's TAoCP has something to say about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a counterexample:

$A = \{10, 12\}$ and $B = \{4, 5, 6, 7\}$.  There is a unique solution: $10=4+6, 12=5+7$.  However your algorithm would do this in its first iteration:

- (step 3): remove plank $10$
- (step 4): manufacture $7$ from $10$ leaving $3$
- (steps 5 & 6): now $A=\{3,12\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6\}$ and it's impossible to complete the job.

More importantly, the problem you pose is a generalization of SUBSET SUM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem
which asks: Given a set of integers $B$, is there a subset that sums to $a_1$?  The SUBSET SUM problem is NP-complete, and is a special case of your problem, and your algorithm is polynomial, which makes it unlikely to work...  :)

Comment: Are you sure the problem is a generalization of SUBSET SUM? What if the B-planks cannot be made from the A-planks, but SUBSET SUM nevertheless has positive answers which lead to dead-ends? (I agree with your counterexample, though.)

Comment: it is a generalization in the sense that, any SUBSET SUM problem can be mapped into a plank problem, s.t. if you can solve the plank problem you can also solve the subset sum.  the mapping is simply: a subset sum problem with inputs $B$ and $a_1$ gets mapped to a plank problem with the same $B$ and $A = \{a_1, sum(B) - a_1\}$.  then the subset sum has a solution iff the plank problem has a solution.  i am not 100% sure "generalization" is the right technical term for this kind of mapping, but this is what i mean.

Comment: I'm not convinced yet. You seem to be considering only a specific class of SUBSET SUM problems.

Comment: according to wikipedia: SUBSET SUM is "given a set of integers [what I call $B$] and an integer s [my $a_1$], does any non-empty subset sum to s?"  I then simply calculate $a_2 = ( \sum_{b \in B} b ) - a_1$ and construct $A=\{a_1, a_2\}$ and consider it a PLANK problem.  If a PLANK algorithm can find a solution, then the $a_1$ part of the PLANK solution solves the original SUBSET SUM problem.

Comment: Oh, you're looking at the equivalent problem! Then I agree.